# may the compiler optimize based on assert(...) expressions/contracts?

Tags: compiler-optimization, d

http://dlang.org/expression.html#AssertExpression

Regarding `assert(0)`: "The optimization and code generation phases of compilation may assume that it is unreachable code."

The same documentation claims `assert(0)` is a 'special case', but there are several reasons that follow.

Can the D compiler optimize based on general `assert`-ions made in contracts and elsewhere?

<sup><sub>(as if I *needed* another reason to enjoy the `in{}` and `out{}` constructs, but it certainly would make me feel a little more giddy to know that writing them could make things go fwoosh-ier)</sub></sup>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In theory, yes, in practice, I don't think it does, especially since the asserts are killed before even getting to the optimizer on dmd -release. I'm not sure about gdc and ldc, but I think they share this portion of the code.

The spec's special case reference btw is that assert(0) is still present, in some form, with the -release compile flag. It is translated into an illegal instruction there (asm {hlt;} - non-kernel programs on x86 aren't allowed to use that so it will segfault upon hitting it), whereas all other asserts are simply left out of the code entirely in -release mode.

Comment: isn't this hlt instruction a problem if you write a kernel in D?

Comment: Maybe, but it is supposed to be unreachable anyway, so you shouldn't be executing it outside of debug mode.

Answer (score 1):

GDC certainly does optimise based on asserts. The if conditions make for much better code, even causing unnecessary code to disappear. However, unfortunately at the moment the way it is implemented is that the entire assert can disappear in release build mode so then the compiler never sees the beneficial if-condition info and actually generates worse code in release than in debug mode! Ironic. I have to admit that I've only looked at this effect with if conditions in asserts in the *body*, I haven't checked what effect in and out blocks have. The in- and out- etc contract blocks can be turned off based on a command line switch iirc, so they are not even compiled, I think this possibly means the compiler doesn't even look at them. So this is another thing that might possibly affect code generation, I haven't looked at it. But there is a feature here that I would very much like to see, that the if condition truth values in the assert conditions (checking that there is no side-effect code in the expression for the assert cond) can always be injected into the compiler as an assumption, just as if there had been an if statement even in release mode. It would involve pretending you had just seen an if ( xxx ) but with the actual code generation for the test suppressed in release mode, and with subsequent code feeling the beneficial effects of say known truth values, value-range limits and so on.